# Spring batch late binding for stepExecutionContext not working

Tags: spring, lazy-initialization, late-binding

I am using Spring batch application and want to use late binding for stepExecutionContext. I am facing issues in resolving my error.

Following is my reader which has sql property using late binding:

```
<bean id="itemReader_S4_JPolicy" class="com.aegonusa.etl.readers.JDBCItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="jobParameters" ref="jobParameters" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="readDataSource" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
    <bean class="com.aegonusa.etl.readers.ResultSetRowMapper" scope="step" />
    </property>
    <property name="sql"
        value="#{stepExecutionContext['readQuery']}"></property>
</bean>
```

I set this property ('readQuery') in following class:

public class StepListener implements StepExecutionListener
{

....
....

```
@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution execution) {
            String s = "select getdate();
    StepSynchronizationManager.getContext().setAttribute("readQuery", s);
```

.....
        }
.....
}

Please note that I am able to do late binding using jobParameters.
But using stepExecutionContext, I get following exc. I tried lot of posts in forums but am unable to resolve it:

```
Throwable occurred: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lazyBindingProxy.itemReader_S4_JPolicy#sysinit' defined in class path resource [Load_InforceToStage.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot bind to placeholder: stepExecutionContext['readQuery']
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:150)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.util.PlaceholderTargetSource.getTarget(PlaceholderTargetSource.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:184)
at $Proxy1.close(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.close(CompositeItemStream.java:83)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.close(ChunkMonitor.java:99)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.close(CompositeItemStream.java:83)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.close(TaskletStep.java:297)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:255)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:349)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
at com.ebsadm.lh.LHSHEDToStage.runJob(LHSHEDToStage.java:124)
at com.ebsadm.lh.LHSHEDToStage.main(LHSHEDToStage.java:111)
at com.ebdadm.lh.TestLHSHEDToStage.testInforceLoadToStage(TestLHSHEDToStage.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot bind to placeholder: stepExecutionContext['readQuery']
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.util.PlaceholderTargetSource$1.convertIfNecessary(PlaceholderTargetSource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    ... 50 more

Kindly help.

Comment: Your `ResultSetRowMapper` is already step scoped, as it it bound to the lifecycle of the enclosing bean (which is already step scoped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect a call to `getExecutionContext` on the `StepExecution` to give you the proper context.

```
@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution execution) {
    String s = "select getdate()";
    execution.getExecutionContext().putString("readQuery", s);  
}
```

Your current solution is getting the `StepContext`. The `StepContext` is the object that is exposed and used for expression parsing, whereas the `ExecutionContext` associated with the `StepExecution` is the actual stepExecutionContext. `ItemReaders` and `ItemWriters` and such object also use the `ExecutionContext` to update the state (skipped items, commit count etc.).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm. However, I am unable to understand the difference between context obtained from execution.getExecutionContext() and context obtained from StepSynchronizationManager.getContext(). How are they different ?

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the below :

1. Use promotionListener bean to promote the scope of variable from step to job.
2. Use bean instead of executionContext.