# What are the Spring Batch "default" Context Variables?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-el

In the [Spring Batch *step-scope* documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope), there are three unexplained spring-batch context maps: `jobParameters`, `jobExecutionContext`, and `stepExecutionContext`.

Springsource sample code, combined:

```
<bean id="flatFileItemReader" scope="step"
  class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="var1" value="#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}" />
    <property name="var2" value="#{jobExecutionContext['input.file.name']}" />
    <property name="var3" value="#{stepExecutionContext['input.file.name']}" />
</bean>
```

What are the default parameters available within `jobParameters`, `jobExecutionContext`, and `stepExecutionContext`?

There are also likely differences between what's available in Spring Batch version 1.x vs. 2.x vs. 3.x--the documentation is pretty scarce in this area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#{jobParameters}`, `#{jobExecutionContext}` and `#{stepExecutionContext}` are the spEL (Spring Expression Language) counterpart of [JobParameters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.html), [JobExecution](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecution.html) and [StepExecution](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html) objects available in late-binding to allow non-static access to this objects values from step scoped object.

They support access as `Map`s so you can access the [ExecutionContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ExecutionContext.html) associated to `JobExecution` and `StepExecution` and values stored in `JobParameters`.

Also check [StepScope](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/StepScope.html) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 5):

There aren't any default values. Think of `jobParameters`, `jobExecutionContext`, and `stepExecutionContext` as glorified `Map`s with helper methods for different primitive data types, e.g. `getInt()`. They're typically accessed from the `StepExecution` and `JobExecution` objects passed to `*ExecutionListener`s, or injecting using value injection, e.g. `@Value("#{jobParameters['foo']}")`.

In this case, `input.file.name` is just a name chosen by the developer, e.g. maybe corresponding to a command line job parameter specified to the `CommandLineJobRunner`.

Comment: Just to clarify: in order add custom variables to my `StepExecution` within the `step` scope, I extended `StepExecution` and instantiated `MyStepExecution` during the Spring Batch partitioning phase.  The job-level parameters ended up being not needed.

Comment: So adding your custom variables to `StepExecution.getExecutionContext()` didn't work? It's the usual way to do it. The accepted answer to this question shows an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830994/spring-batch-late-binding-for-stepexecutioncontext-not-working

Comment: Yes, that did work, but I didn't like the testability of it--seemed like too much `String` fudging; less semantic.  I liked the declarative getters.

Comment: Ah, OK. The reason for those particular data types is that they are straightforward to persist in the SERIALIZED_CONTEXT clob of the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT table in the Spring Batch RDBMS schema. (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html) Be careful that your customisations don't get lost on resuming failed jobs.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/reference/html/index.html)

JobParameters are parameters passed in when starting the job

The execution contexts are for your use to store whatever you want. Typically, the step execution context will contain information to allow the step to restart (for restartable jobs).

Elements in the step execution context can be [promoted to the job execution context](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/ExecutionContextPromotionListener.html) if you want to communicate information between steps.