# How to get Job Parameter?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch version 2.1.8. The job context shown as below:

```xml
<job id="job1" restartable="true"  >
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="reader" writer="writter" processor="processor"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
    <validator ref="jobParameterValidator"></validator> 
</job>
```

The `jobParamterValidator` is to get the file name and do some validation on filename.

So my question is how can I get the `fileName` at `processor="processor"`, because want to validate filename with data? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

use `#{jobParameters['fileName']}`, but you need to mark your step with `scope="step"` else placeholder doesn't work.
You can read more at [What are the Spring Batch "default" Context Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205778/what-are-the-spring-batch-default-context-variables/22208521#22208521)

Comment: #{jobParameters['fileName']} is put at which context? itemReader or itemProccessor? Because my itemReader is like this <beans:bean id="iItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
   <beans:property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['fileName']}" />
   <beans:property name="lineMapper" ref="lineMapper" />
 </beans:bean>

Comment: you are fine with definition posted in your comment

Comment: How can i access the job parameter from Java coding site? Thanks

Comment: use `StepExecutionListener.beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution)` and `stepExecution.getJobParameters()`

Comment: Sorry i still cant get your point how to do it. My reader is like this :  <beans:bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
   <beans:property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['fileName']}" />
   <beans:property name="lineMapper" ref="testingLineMapper" />
 </beans:bean>
So how to access the fileName from "resource" in Java?

Comment: write a custom processor and inject #{jobParameters['fileName']} into.

Comment: Yes I have testingLineMapper which will refer to custom class. I am use 
    @Value("#{jobParameters['resource']}")
    private String resource; 
to inject. Unfortunately there is error occurs.