# Saving and accessing number of rows retrieved by JdbcCursorItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

Our Spring Batch application has:a custom **JdbcCursorItemReader** which reads from the database, and a custom **JmsItemWriter**, which enables headers to added to each message.

The idea is that each message will have a correlation id and be part of a set. Within the JmsItemWriter, we need to access the total number of rows which the item reader retrieved.

What is the best approach to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the TOTAL count of rows (eg the `select count(*) from table`) the best choice is to create a previous step where you perform the count and put the result into execution-context to access it in next steps.
If you need the number of current record `JdbcCursorItemReader` inherits this facilities from [`AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html)

Comment: Thanks very much. What is the best way to access the execution context from an ItemProcessor or ItemWriter ?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205778/what-are-the-spring-batch-default-context-variables/22208521#22208521

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Would this work (and avoid having both to have an extra step and to hit the DB with an extra query): 1. Create a custom JdbcCursorItemReader 2. Inject into it the execution context (<property name="var2" value="#{jobExecutionContext}/>) 3. In JdbcCursorItemReader.cleanUpOnClose() call getCurrentItemCount(); 4. Save that value in the execution context?

Comment: Maybe.You have to try. But I prefer an extra step because I think it is more readable (or implement `StepExecutionListener.beforeStep()` to perform `select count` if you don't want to create an extra step)

Comment: Thanks. Here is what I am not understanding: how from an item writer, processor or reader, to get hold of the StepExecutionContext itself so as to then add a variable to it (as opossed to getting the value of a variable which is already in it). Is that possible?

Comment: Use listeners. Or extend or delegate reader, writer or processor

Comment: When extending reader, writer or processor, what base class functionality exposes the stepExecutionListener ?

Comment: sir, I'm not a human javadoc ;) I answered your question and more... please read official documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/ about listeners

Comment: Great - implement ItemStream - very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the StepListener, see following example :

```java
@Component
public class StepListener extends StepExecutionListenerSupport {

  @Override
  public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    // here, you can debug stepExecution to get some values like "readCount" :
    logger.info(stepExecution.getReadCount());

    // you also have commitCount, writeCount, rollbackCount, readSkipCount, writeSkipCount, processSkipCount, filterCount

    // check stepExecution.getSummary for a nice one line info
    logger.info(stepExecution.getSummary());

    return null;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to configure your stepListener in the Step of the Batch configuration